# how to generate MSTEST results in Static folders

Tags: mstest, coded-ui-tests

Is there a way to control the name of the MSTEST video recoding file names or the folder names with the test name. It seems to generate different guid everytime and thus very difficult to map the test with its corresponding video recording files.

The only solution I can see is to read the TRX file and map the guid to Test Name.

Any suggestions ??

[image: Mstest Result Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not opposed to doing it by hand, it's pretty easy. I encountered the same problem, and needed them to be somewhere predictable so I could email links to the videos. In the end my solution just ended up being to code in the functionality by hand. It's a bit involved, but not too difficult.

First, you'll need to have [Expression Encoder 4](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/encoder4_overview.aspx) installed.

Then you'll need to add these references to your project:

```
Microsoft.Expression.Encoder
Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Api2
Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Types
Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Utilities
```

Next, you need to add the following inclusion statements:

```
using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Profiles;
using Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.ScreenCapture;
```

Then you can use [TestInitialize] and [TestCleanup] to define the correct behavior. These methods will run at the beginning and end of each test respectively. This can be done something like this:

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void startVideoCapture()
    {
            screenCapJob.CaptureRectangle = RectangleSelectionUtilities.GetScreenRect(0);
            screenCapJob.CaptureMouseCursor = true;
            screenCapJob.ShowFlashingBoundary = false;

            screenCapJob.OutputScreenCaptureFileName = "path you want to save to";

            screenCapJob.Start();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void stopVideoCapture()
    {
            screenCapJob.Stop();
    }
```

Obviously this code needs some error and edge case handling, but it should get you started.
You should also know that the free version of Expression Encoder 4 limits you to 10 minutes per video file, so you may want to make a timer that will start a new video for you when it hits 10 minutes.